# Is there a way to have consistent strokeWidth across devices?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a multiplatform project where I draw some points with

```
drawPoints(dataPts, PointMode.Points, Color.Blue, strokeWidth = 5f)
```

The point size appear proper on Linux desktop but is too small on Android phone.  Is there a way to have roughly similar presentation?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your [dp](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/unit/Dp) to px before drawing with DrawScope

```
val strokeWidth = with(LocalDensity.current) {
    2.dp.toPx()
}
Canvas(modifier=Modifier) {
    // you can set here too
    val strokeWidth =   2.dp.toPx()

    drawPoints(listOf(Offset(100f,100f)), PointMode.Points, Color.Blue, strokeWidth = strokeWidth)

}
```

Comment: Thanks.  That works.  Perhaps it's better it gets included in the drawing routines somewhere.